# Padding, margin, and background color won't disappear

Tags: jquery, html, css, background, padding

## Background

I am trying to make a fixed navbar with a dropdown in one of the options. On smaller screens, the menu overlay would reveal all options displayed vertically in the middle of the screen. I do not want the background color/hover on any of the links in the small screen version. The nav background should just be `#fff` or `#111`, depending on the theme you're using (change "light" to "dark" in .mobile-menu and in nav to see the other menu theme). Screen widths are just placeholders for testing. I have some remnants of an old version left in the JavaScript (like `navList`) – sorry about that – please just ignore that stuff.

## The Problems

- The background color on the sub-links as well as the background hover color won't go away.
- The link that has sub-links is too tall, and I can't seem to get rid of its padding/margin.

## What I've Tried

I have tried overriding with

```
* { background-color: transparent }
```

and

```
* { padding: 0; margin: 0 }
```

at the bottom of my small screen media query to no avail, as well as resetting these properties on the individual elements and/or classes of elements.

I've also tried using `<a>` instead of `<div>` for Link 2 (`.dropbtn`), but that causes `.dropdown-content` to appear right on top of Link 2, rather than starting right beneath it. I was able to fix that with something kludgy like `top: 47px` on `.dropdown-content`, but really preferred how using `<div>` caused the menu to properly display beneath Link 2 (and couldn't find the parameter that would've caused an `<a>` Link 2 to behave like the `<div>`).

Disabling all of the JavaScript did not fix it either.

## The Code

Here's what I've got so far:
https://jsfiddle.net/heyycap/2p0zq61e/1355/

```js
var mobile = $('.mobile-menu')
var navList = $('nav > ul')
var winHeight
var docHeight
var throttleScroll
var scrollTop
var nav = $('nav')
var light = $('.light')
var dark = $('.dark')
var breakPoint = 600
var windowSize = 0
var newWindowSize = 0
var lightColor = '#fff'
var darkColor = '#111'

var scrollDiv = document.createElement("div");
scrollDiv.className = "scrollbar-measure";
document.body.appendChild(scrollDiv);
var scrollbarWidth = scrollDiv.offsetWidth - scrollDiv.clientWidth;
document.body.removeChild(scrollDiv);
console.info('Scrollbar: ' + scrollbarWidth + 'px')

function styleLightDark() {
  light.css({
    'background-color': lightColor,
    'color': darkColor
  })
  dark.css({
    'background-color': darkColor,
    'color': lightColor
  })
}

function styleMobileMenu() {
  if (mobile.hasClass('light')) {
    mobile.css('background-color', lightColor)
  } else {
    mobile.css('background-color', darkColor)
  }
}

function styleNav() {
  if ($('nav').hasClass('light')) {
    $('nav').css('background-color', lightColor)
  } else {
    $('nav').css('background-color', darkColor)
  }
}

function remBg() {
  light.css('background-color', '')
  dark.css('background-color', '')
}

function changeNav(x) {
  if (windowSize == 'small') {
    if (x <= breakPoint) {
      nav.hide()
    }
  }
  if (windowSize == 'large') {
    if (x > breakPoint) {
      nav.fadeIn(500)
    }
  }
}

function checkWindowSize(x) {
  if (x <= breakPoint) {
    newWindowSize = 'small'
  }
  if (x > breakPoint) {
    newWindowSize = 'large'
  }
}

function getMeasurements() {
  var winHeight = $(window).height()
  var docHeight = $(document).height()
  var trackLength = docHeight - winHeight
  var innerWidth = $(document).width()
  var widthWithScrollbar = innerWidth + scrollbarWidth
  amountScrolled()
  console.info('Width - scrollbar, if it exists: ' + innerWidth + 'px')
  if (winHeight == docHeight) {
    checkWindowSize(innerWidth)
    if (windowSize != newWindowSize) {
      windowSize = newWindowSize
      changeNav(innerWidth)
    }
  } else {
    checkWindowSize(widthWithScrollbar)
    if (windowSize != newWindowSize) {
      windowSize = newWindowSize
      changeNav(widthWithScrollbar)
    }
  }
}

function amountScrolled() {
  scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop()
  console.info('Scrolled: ' + scrollTop + 'px')
  if ((scrollTop < 5) && (innerWidth > breakPoint)) {
    remBg()
  } else if ((scrollTop < 5) && (nav.is(':hidden')) && (innerWidth <= breakPoint)) {
    remBg()
  } else if ((!nav.is(':hidden')) && (innerWidth <= breakPoint)) {
    mobile.css('background-color', '')
  } else if ((scrollTop >= 5) && (nav.is(':hidden')) && (innerWidth <= breakPoint)) {
    remBg()
    styleMobileMenu()
  } else if ((scrollTop >= 5) && (innerWidth > breakPoint)) {
    styleLightDark()
  }
}

getMeasurements()

$(window).on('resize', function() {
  getMeasurements()
})

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  clearTimeout(throttleScroll);
  throttleScroll = setTimeout(function() {
    amountScrolled()
  }, 10)
})

mobile.on('click', function() {
  scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop()
  if (nav.is(':hidden')) {
    nav.fadeIn(500)
    remBg()
    styleNav()
  } else if ((!nav.is(':hidden')) && (scrollTop > 5)) {
    nav.fadeOut(500)
    remBg()
    styleMobileMenu()
  } else {
    nav.fadeOut(500)
    remBg()
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: 50px 0;
}

.mobile-menu {
  display: none;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  opacity: .9;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

nav a {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  padding: 14px 16px;
}

nav.dark a:hover,
nav.dark .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #111;
}

nav.light a:hover,
nav.light .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #111;
  color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

#navigation,
#resources,
.resources {
  display: none;
}

.light * {
  color: #111;
}

.dark * {
  color: #fff;
}

.dark .dropdown-content {
  background-color: #111;
}

.light .dropdown-content {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.scrollbar-measure {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
}


/* MEDIA QUERIES */

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .mobile-menu {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: right;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 3;
    height: auto;
    opacity: .9;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  nav {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    display: none;
  }
  nav>div {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
  nav a,
  .dropdown,
  #navigation,
  #resources,
  .resources,
  .dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    padding: 1px 0;
  }
  .dropdown-content,
  .dropbtn {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #navigation:after {
    content: "Navigation";
  }
  #resources:after {
    content: "Resources";
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <a class="mobile-menu light">menu</a>
  <nav class="light">
    <div>
      <div id="navigation"></div>
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <div href="#" class="dropbtn">Link 2</div>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 2-1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2-2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2-3</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2-4</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2-5</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      <a href="#">Link 4</a>
      <a href="#">Link 5</a>
      <a href="#">Link 6</a>
      <a href="#">Link 7</a>
      <div id="resources"></div>
      <div class="resources">
        <a href="#">Link 8</a>
        <a href="#">Link 9</a>
        <a href="#">Link 10</a>
        <a href="#">Link 11</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <section>
    <p>Test text</p>
    <p>some text to wrap : some text to wrap : some text to cause scrolling : : some text to wrap : some text to wrap : some text to cause scrolling : : some text to wrap : some text to wrap : some text to cause scrolling : : some text to wrap : some text
      to wrap : some text to cause scrolling : : some text to wrap : some text to wrap : some text to cause scrolling : : some text to wrap : some text to wrap : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>some text to cause scrolling : </p>
    <p>Last bit of text</p>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you used the developer tools in your browser? They are super useful in cases like this. To open them press [F12] in your browser. Read up on how to use them here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these styles using media query

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  nav.light a:hover, nav.light .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
      background-color: transparent;
      color: black;
  }
  .dropdown .dropbtn {
    padding: 0 16px;
  }
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2p0zq61e/1365/)

Comment: Thank you – I was able to merge this suggestion into my other existing media query.